# Even though method exist in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have button ok in that I'm calling method of Xyz sheet. But when I click that ok button causing method or data member not found. Even though the method exist in Xyz sheet.but sheet is protected.im doing unprotect before processing code. Why am I getting error even the proper method exist?

```
Dim wsWarnErr As Object

   If BC_FC_RadioButton.Value Then
    Call wsWarnErr.GroupByBC_FC
  End If
```

after the above change getting error as'Object variable or with block variable not set'

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the error is ? snippet of your function in the question. Also, would be a check if you can add a new button in your sheet and tie it up with the macro you want to call, just as a check.

Comment: Declare your sheet variable as `Object`, not as `Worksheet`.  Even better, *post your code*

Comment: Where in your code do you set `wsWarnErr`?

Comment: Try`Worksheets("wsWarnErr").GroupByBC_FC`

Answer (score 2):

Say you have this in your `Sheet1` code module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SayHello()
    Debug.Print "Hello"
End Sub
```

If you try this in a regular module:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheet1
sht.SayHello
```

you will get a compile error "Method or data member not found".

Your method is there *but* you are declaring sht as type `Worksheet`, and the "out of the box" Worksheet type doesn't have a `SayHello` method, so you get that error.

If instead you use

```
Dim sht As Sheet1
```

or

```
Dim sht As Object
```

you won't see the error, since the `Sheet1` type *does* have that method, and the call to the late-bound `As Object` reference resolves at run-time.

Comment: now i changed my code as you said above. but now im getting error as,'object variable or With block variable not set'.

Comment: @tim-williams Very interesting solution! I learned something new. Thanks Tim!